# Copy 18 rows and paste transposed, repeat until end of data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I am a beginner with Google Sheets macros.
I have a spreadsheet with 468 rows in column a.
I want to copy 18 rows, paste transposed beginning in column b1.
Then move to next 18 rows (19-37) and repeat until end of data.
Should end up with transposed data in rows 1,19,37,55, etc.
I tried recording a macro; however, I cannot get it to move to the next group of data.

Comment: I think people might find it helpful to see what the macro looks like so they can try to modify it

Comment: This can be achieved without a macro by putting the following in b1 and dragging down =index(A$1:A,18-mod(row(A1)-1,18)+18*quotient(row(A1)-1,18))

Answer (score 0):

I recorded a macro using relative cell references and a relatively simple assignment strategy (just setting the contents = to that of the right cell for each of the 18 cells). I then encased that in a for loop so that it repeats. When I start in B1 and run it, it does what you want. Clearly there are are many ways you could continue to enhance it, such as making the indentation nicer, making 468 something more like the number of rows or explaining in a comment what 18 is. You could even rewrite the macro that was recorded with a for loop. But this should get you started.

```
function SOrevSheetRange() {


 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var i;
  for (i=0; i<468/18; i++){
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=R[17]C[-1]');
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=R[15]C[-1]');
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=R[13]C[-1]');
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=R[11]C[-1]');
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=R[9]C[-1]');
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=R[7]C[-1]');
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=R[5]C[-1]');
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=R[3]C[-1]');
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=R[1]C[-1]');
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=R[-1]C[-1]');
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=R[-3]C[-1]');
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=R[-5]C[-1]');
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=R[-7]C[-1]');
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=R[-9]C[-1]');
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=R[-11]C[-1]');
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=R[-13]C[-1]');
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=R[-15]C[-1]');
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=R[-17]C[-1]');
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
  }
};
```

As I noted in an earlier comment, it is possible to do this whole task without a macro, but my understanding is you want to get used to macros, so I am giving this answer.
Revision: It was bothering me how long this was, so I did the rewriting what was recorded as a loop. That looks like:

```
function SOrevSheetRange() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var i;
var j;
for (i = 0; i < 468 / 18; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 18; j++) {
        spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=R[' + (17 - 2 * j) + ']C[-1]');
        spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
    }
    }
};
```